# Word 2013 - Lag on saving documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

There appears to be a lag, after saving a document.

When I save a document to `My Documents`, the file is never there.

I can go back to "Recent Documents", open the word doc, save the file to the same location and it will do the same thing again. No error message and no "File already exists with the same name".

The weird part is the document will eventually appear, it can take up to a day.

Why is this? How do i fix it?

Comment: Are you using SkyDrive/One Drive? You may get a lag if you are saving directly in the cloud.

Comment: How many files are there in "My Documents"? try a disc cleanup, system file clearnup and other utilities like ccleaer, even more than one utilities. Also, defragment your harddisk if it is not set to automatic maintenance. Also run your HDD health check up, maybe it is nearing its end. Go to your Autorecover (File - Info - Manage document) and delete all files and autorecover segment. Also go to HDD folder of autorecover in Windows Explorer and delete things there.